Multiplication operator is a closed
Let $\phi$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. We define the multiplication operator $M_{\phi}$ on the following domain $D = \{f \in H^{2}(\mathbb{D}): \phi f \in H^{2}(\mathbb{D})\}$, where $H^{2}(\mathbb{D})$ is the Hardy space of analytic function in the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$. The multiplication operator $M_{\phi}$ is defined by
$$(M_{\phi}f)(z) = \phi(z)f(z)$$ for $f \in D$.
I would like to show that $M_{\phi}$ is a closed operator. Hence I have to take a sequence $\{f_{n}\} \in D$ with $f_{n} \longrightarrow f \in H^{2}(\mathbb{D})$ and $\phi f_{n} \longrightarrow g$ with convergence in the $L^{2}$ norm. I have to show that $f \in D$ and that $\phi f = g  \;\;a.e.$.
Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Hint: a sequence converging in $L^2$ implies a subsequence converges almost everywhere to the same limit.
